I want to draw two Z axes, two X axes, and two Y axes in a 3-dimensional graph in MATLAB. But "yyaxis" doesn't work
Note: Each coordinate system corresponds to a different surface, and all surfaces here should belong to the same 3D diagram.
I tried the code "yyaxis", but this code is only applicable to the drawing of two-dimensional graphs. Thank you very much. Here is an example.You can see that the two coordinates overlap.
close;
clc;
clear;

x = linspace(-2, 2, 50);
y = linspace(-2, 2, 50);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z1 = sin(X) .* cos(Y);
Z2 = X.^2 + Y.^2;

figure;
surf(X, Y, Z1);
hold on;

ax2 = axes('Position',get(gca,'Position'),'Color','none');
set(ax2,'XAxisLocation','top','YAxisLocation','right','ZDir','reverse');
view(ax2,3);
hold(ax2,'on');
surf(X, Y, Z2,'Parent',ax2);

xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z1');
zlabel(ax2,'Z2');
title('Double Z-axis 3D Plot');
hold off;


Are you just looking for hold on which would let you plot multiple surfaces on the same axes? If not then how do you expect to overlay multiple 3D plots in any sort of clear way?

You can create two axes, with one plot in each, and then change their position and size so that they’re on top of each other (set the position property of both axes to be the same). But I echo Wolfie’s sentiment: this is not going to be pretty.

@Wolfie Thanks for your advice. In fact, the two 3D drawings I made are already "hold on" in one diagram. But the data varies too much, and after "hold on," the image becomes very small.

@Cris Luengo Thanks for your advice. In fact, it doesn't work. If I can have the same effect as "yyaxis" in a two-dimensional graph, I think I can set the range of coordinates so that the two surfaces can be very clear, but not overlapping. As I said above, the data of the two surfaces are so different that after "hold on" they both become small. I need to find a way to make them more clear.

In fact, the problem can be solved by breaking axes, such as "breaxaxis" or "breakyaxis", but unfortunately, they are adapted to two-dimensional graphs.

“Thanks for your advice. In fact, it doesn't work.” It does, but you probably are doing something wrong. Why don’t you [edit] your post to include the code you tried (see [mre]), then we at least know what is going on. Makes helping you so much easier.

@Cris Luengo I added the code, I hope you can see it.

That is an excellent MRE, thank you! So XAxisLocation and YAxisLocation don't work, and there's no ZAxisLocation, which is the one you'd really want to set. That is a problem, you're right! (I figured if this works in 2D it should work in 3D as well, sorry.) ---- I would suggest going the subplot route instead.

@Cris Luengo Well, using "subplot" should be my last resort, if there's really nothing else to do. Thanks again for your advice.

An alternative would be to just scale your data - if the issue is an order of magnitude difference when using hold on then maybe you can plot X,Y,Z*1e3 instead of X,Y,X and reflect that in your axis labels i.e. "widgets (000s)" instead of "widgets", or use offset and use X,Y,Z+c and use custom zticklabels to reflect both datasets
